# Need a regex to fetch only the Anchor tag from the below code snippet.

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the anchor tag alone from the below code snippet. I am very new to Regex i tried using `(<li><a .*>.*<\/a><\/li>)`, this brings me all the code like this `<li><a xlink:href="" title="" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>`

but i need the regex to bring me the individual anchor tag, instead of the complete structure. like `<li><a xlink:href="" title="" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>` and `<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>` and `<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>` etc.

Source is below.

`<tmproot><h4 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h4><p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<br /></p><p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<br /></p><ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><ul>
<li><a xlink:href="" title="" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
<li><a title="" xlink:href="tcm:" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title=""></a></li>
</ul></ul></tmproot>`

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: have you tried using a XML parser or a lexer? it is more suited for your purpose then regex

Comment: @user2310343 Have you seen the answer I provided?  Does fix your problem?  Whilst I agree that an XML parser is your best bet, if you want to go with regex, hopefully my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `(<li><a .*>.*<\/a><\/li>)` use `<li>(<a .*>.*<\/a>)<\/li>`.

Note the different positioning of the ().  () is what you're capturing, so if you just want the anchor tag, wrap the anchor part of the regex in ().

Javascript example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
var txt = el.value;
var res = txt.match(/<li>(<a .*>.*<\/a>)<\/li>/g);
for(var x in res){
  console.log(res[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem whith your regex is that `.*` is greedy, i.e. it matches as much as possible. In most languages, adding a `?` makes it reluctant : `(<li><a .*?>.*?<\/a><\/li>)`

That said, parsing XML whith regex is usually not a good idea, there are a lot of traps and corner cases, e.g what happen if the markup contains comments or CDATA ?